# Exchanging different kinds of data between threads in Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, design-patterns, signals-slots

That's kind of design question. Say, I have a worker thread and a GUI thread. The worker thread does some work and the GUI must show the information about current status of this work (for example, worker can process some files and the GUI must show the number of processed files, having separate counters for different types of files).

In Qt the information exchange between threads should be done via signals-slots mechanism. But if I have a lot of different kinds of information to pass from thread to thread, should I create different signals for each type of information (for example, for each type of file), or it would be better to create one signal (for example, `informationUpdated(InfoContainer);` with a special struct (`InfoContainer`), which will store the data I want to pass?

Comment: I would prefer the `InfoContainer`-way. You can create a single datamember in your class that can be thread-safely be queried by `getInfo()`. And when new info is available, you can emit `infoUpdated()` which will inform the GUI that it can retrieve new information. This relieves you of registering your type with the meta-type system (for queued signals to work). Alternatively, you could send `infoUpdated(QVariant)`, and store a `QMap<QString,QVariant>` inside of the variant (supported out of the box).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends on what kind of data types you are going to emit.

1- If they are simple non-structured types, you can use [QVariant](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) which can handle [many types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#canConvert) ( primitives and Qt types like QString, QPoint etc)

2- Alternatively, you can use a container class like [QMap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html) to pass a list of QVariant as  *Johannes Schaub* said in the comment.

3- You may also want to create *your own Message class which is integrated with the meta-object system*. Then, convert it to [QVariant](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) to be emitted. Here is a good [Custom Type Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-tools-customtype-example.html) from Qt documentation.

I choose the **last method** for better integration and expandability.